# How to call to angular ajax function from angular controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

this is my code

```
$scope.GetLocatoinByCountry();

$scope.GetLocatoinByCountry = function () {
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/JobPost/GetLocationByCountry',
            data: { countryId: $scope.draftJobPost.countryID }
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            var loc = response.data;
            $scope.locations = response.data;
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            var error = response;
        });
    };
```

but get an error

> TypeError: $scope.GetLocatoinByCountry is not a function

how to solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the calling function below the assignation:

```
$scope.GetLocatoinByCountry = function() {
  $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/JobPost/GetLocationByCountry',
    data: {
      countryId: $scope.draftJobPost.countryID
    }
  }).then(function successCallback(response) {
    var loc = response.data;
    $scope.locations = response.data;
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    var error = response;
  });
};

$scope.GetLocatoinByCountry(); // move it here
```

> *TypeError: $scope.GetLocatoinByCountry **is not a function***

The error says everything.

The issue was you were calling the function where it wasn't existed in the `$scope` and you were assigning the function to the `$scope` later on.

Comment: @SasikaMiyuran You are welcome and glad this helped you.

Answer (score 0):

I think when using Angular 1 you can use $http or $resouce for calling API.

In your case: move the line `$scope.GetLocatoinByCountry();` from above to below can make it work.